# Topological transversality by dimension

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, differential-topology, manifolds

We know that to achieve transverality in the topological category, for example to make a continuous map into a manifold transverse to a topological submanifold, we need the existence of micro normal bundle. A simple case of transverse intersection is that two submanifolds do not intersect for dimension reason. For example, two 1 dimensional submanifolds are transverse in a 3-dimensional manifold if and only if they have empty intersection. I wonder in such situation (transverse is equivalent to no intersection by dimension reason), to achieve transversality by slightly perturbing objects, do we still need the existence of micro normal bundle.

Comment: Cant you just approximate everything by smooth maps and use smooth transversality? Yopological 3 folds can be equipped with a smooth structure

Comment: @ThomasRot Then how about general situation? I want only to perturb one object (map or submanifold) but fixing the other submanifold.

Comment: Dancis' paper may be relevant: https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1976-216-00/S0002-9947-1976-0391098-9/

Comment: @UVIR: I dont know much about topological trabsversality in general unfortunately. So i cannot help further